# Kubernetes on Mesos, no suitable offer available

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos

I followed the instructions on [this page](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) to build and deploy Mesos. I did this on a Ubuntu Trusty VM with 1 Mesos master and 1 slave. The following commands are what I used to run Mesos.

```
$ mesos-master --ip=10.0.2.15 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --log_dir=/var/log/mesos
$ mesos-slave --master=10.0.2.15:5050 --containerizers=docker,mesos
```

All of three tests finished without error message.

Then I followed [this page](http://kubernetes.github.io/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos/) to deploy Kubernetes. After building Kubernetes-Mesos, I used the following commands to deploy Kubernetes.

```
$ export KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP=10.0.2.15
$ export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:8888
$ docker run -d --hostname $(uname -n) --name etcd \
  -p 4001:4001 -p 7001:7001 quay.io/coreos/etcd:v2.0.12 \
  --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:4001
```

etcd container is running.

```
$ export PATH="$(pwd)/_output/local/go/bin:$PATH"
$ export MESOS_MASTER=10.0.2.15:5050
$ cat <<EOF >mesos-cloud.conf
  [mesos-cloud]
        mesos-master        = ${MESOS_MASTER}
  EOF
$ km apiserver \
  --address=${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP} \
  --etcd-servers=http://${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:4001 \
  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.10.10.0/24 \
  --port=8888 \
  --cloud-provider=mesos \
  --cloud-config=mesos-cloud.conf \
  --secure-port=0 \
  --v=1 >apiserver.log 2>&1 &
$ km controller-manager \
  --master=${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:8888 \
  --cloud-provider=mesos \
  --cloud-config=./mesos-cloud.conf  \
  --v=1 >controller.log 2>&1 &
$ km scheduler \
  --address=${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP} \
  --mesos-master=${MESOS_MASTER} \
  --etcd-servers=http://${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:4001 \
  --mesos-user=root \
  --api-servers=${KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP}:8888 \
  --cluster-dns=10.10.10.10 \
  --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
  --v=2 >scheduler.log 2>&1 &
```

Logs seem correct, no error message.

`kubectl get services` shows:

```
NAME             CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
k8sm-scheduler   10.10.10.50   <none>        10251/TCP   1m
kubernetes       10.10.10.1    <none>        443/TCP     2m
```

Then I created a simple nginx pod, `kubectl get pods` always shows it's pending. `kubectl get events` shows:

```
FIRSTSEEN   LASTSEEN   COUNT     NAME      KIND      SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON             SOURCE                 MESSAGE
2m          47s        9         nginx     Pod                   Warning   FailedScheduling   {default-scheduler }   Error scheduling: No suitable offers for pod/task
```

What does it mean by **No suitable offers for pod/task**? In Mesos' log, I see Mesos keeps sending offer to Kubernetes framework, but keeps being DECLINED. If I run `mesos-execute --master=10.0.2.15:5050 --name=echo --command="echo 'hello world'" --containerizer=docker --docker_image=ubuntu:14.04` it can deploy a Docker image with "mesos-" prefix and run the command. So it seems Docker containerizer works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes-Mesos will decline offers for several reasons:

1. the resources in the offer don't satisfy the minimum required to launch the pod-task. The first pod-task launched on a given slave requires executor resources in addition to the pod-task resources.
2. the resources in the offer aren't compatible with the scheduler. this happens if you start the framework, launch a task, kill the scheduler process, then restart the scheduler with different flags; some scheduler flags affect the command-line used to launch the executor. the quickest way to remedy this is to delete any running pods and manually kill the incompatible executor process(es) already running on the slave(s).
3. there is a problem with the node info in the apiserver registry.

What version of k8sm are you running? master? You might try increasing the verbosity of the scheduler logs (--v=3) and then dumping a copy of your scheduler logs up on pastebin or some such so that they can be analyzed. It's often difficult to troubleshoot situations like this without the logs.

Comment: My k8sm version is v1.2.0-alpha.8, mesos version is 0.27.1.
Here is part of scheduler.log: http://pastebin.com/M0FSsa1i

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the offers that are coming in do not satisfy the needs of Kubernetes. You have to find out what your framework needs, and then compare that to what the rejected offers look like.

Comment: How do I do that? As I know, to run a Kubernetes pod you only need to be able to run Docker image. I've tried to run Docker image using `mesos-execute --master=10.0.2.15:5050 --name=echo --command="echo 'hello world'" --containerizer=docker --docker_image=ubuntu:14.04` and succeeds.

Comment: Every task requires an amount of CPU, memory, and one or several ports to launch. If there are no offers that meet all of those criteria, then the task cannot launch.